# RavenDB Client in UWP App

Tags: uwp, ravendb

Does RavenDB provide client support for UWP applications?

The latest nuget packages appear to support dnxcore5.0 but when I try to install it I receive a message that my platform UAP, Version 10 is not compatible.

I started off with a WPF application and now need to move to a UWP implementation and (embarrassingly) just assumed that their would be client side support for UWP after a years time.

Thanks for your help and feedback.

Comment: We'll have an update for the new .NET Core by the end of the week

Comment: To be clear, I will be able to add the update (when available) to my UWP Windows 10 Store App? Apologies in advance if the answer is obvious but honestly the relationship between .Net Core XYZ, UAP, etc is not very clear to me.  I simply want to access RavenDB from my store app as I have in my WPF app. Thank you very much for your time, support, and patience.

Comment: We are going to look into this today, after publishing the netcoreapp1.0 support.

Comment: Can you try now with this version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/3.5.35142-Unstable

Comment: I am still unable to add the nugget package. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I tried creating a new blank UWP Window 10 app and then Manage Nuget packages to add a reference to RavenDB.Client. The error is _"RavenDB.Client 3.5.35142-unstable is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0."_ and then a bunch of architecture specific "not compatible" AOT messages.

Comment: Any update on UWP? From what I can piece together UWP is supposedly compatible with .netstandard 1.4 and it looks like version from your link specifies .netstanard 1.6. I sure will be glad when the dust settles from the most recent round of MS framework whack-a-mole. Thanks.